# I'm getting firefox security warninng for no particular reason

Tags: html, ajax, security, firefox

I made some changes to my page and since than I'm getting security warning

> The information you have entered on this page will be sent over an insecure connection and could be read by a third party.

I have no idea why, my server is only https, it does not run on http at all. One of the changes I made is submitting the form via ajax instead normal post, but the url is relative, so I don't specify the protocol and it's https already.

The popup appears after the form was submitted.

If I choose "continue" no other request is made. I checked it in firefox network monitor and wireshark capture. I don't see any non https connection there.

the page is https://test.simplecoin.eu, order need to be created, after submitting it the warning pop's up.

Otherwise everything works fine, it just make bad impression

I want to get rid of this message. My firefox is 41.0.1, happens at least on fedora 23 and ubuntu 16.04

Comment: explain close votes please

Answer (score 3):

The problem was, that I was doing "fake" submit to make autocomplete work. I found this on stackoverflow.

```
<iframe name="fakeFormTarget" style="display:none" src="about:blank"> </iframe>
<form target="fakeFormTarget" action="https://about:blank">
```

Adding `https://` to `about:blank` fixed the problem